# How can i get the function result in orderd format haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have two function first one take list

List can be something like :

```
['Sunyy','day',etc','etc']

countOccurrences :: [String] -> [(String, Int)]
countOccurrences xs = map (\xs -> (head xs, length xs)) . group . sort $ xs
```

this function returns something like `[("sunny",1),("etc",2)]`

But I want to call the sortOccurence function with the value that I got from the first function so I can get the value like : `[("etc",2),("sunny",2)]`

```
sortOccurrences :: [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
sortOccurrences sort = sortBy (comparing snd) sort
```

while I execute this function I get an error like :

```
main.hs:13:32: error:
    Variable not in scope:
      comparing
        :: ((a0, b0) -> b0) -> (String, Int) -> (String, Int) -> Ordering
```

Comment: You have to import `comparing` from `Data.Ord`.

Comment: Or import `Data.Function` and use ``compare `on` snd``.

Comment: Or use `sortOn snd`. Btw please don't use `sort` as a name for the argument on `sortOccurrences` as it is the name of a very common function, whereas here it is a list - highly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As [@ReinHenrichs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225384/rein-henrichs) pointed out, this is simply a case of not importing `comparing` from `Data.Ord`. You can rectify this by adding this line at the top of your file:

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
```

In general, when the compiler says `Variable not in scope (...)`, it  means that you've written something that the compiler doesn't know about, and in some way you have to make it aware of what you are referring to. Since `comparing` comes from the module `Data.Ord`, it's not imported by default.